# Erro ao arredondar BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, double

Estou realizando um cálculo com dois métodos, só que como os atributos são do tipo `double`, estou usando o `BigDecimal` para realizar a operação e após isso converter para duas casas decimais apenas.

Estou tendo dificuldade na conversão, já tentei de duas formas:

```
public double CalcularQntConsumido (){

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(consumo.getRegistro());
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(ds.getBuscarRegistro());
    BigDecimal bd3 = new BigDecimal(ds.getUltimoConsumo());


    if(ds.BuscarConsumo().size() == 0){

        qntConsumido =  bd.subtract(bd2).doubleValue();
        bd = new BigDecimal(qntConsumido);
        bd.setScate(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
        double valorFormatado = bd.doubleValue();
        return valorFormatado;


    }

    else{


        qntConsumido = bd.subtract(bd3).doubleValue();
        bd = new BigDecimal(qntConsumido);
        bd.setScate(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
        double valorFormatado = bd.doubleValue();
        return valorFormatado;

    }

}
```

E dessa forma:

```
public double CalcularQntConsumido (){

    if(ds.BuscarConsumo().size() == 0){

        qntConsumido = consumo.getRegistro() - ds.getBuscarRegistro();
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(qntConsumido);
        bd.setScate(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);  
        double valorFormatado = bd.doubleValue();
        return valorFormatado;


    }

    else{

        qntConsumido = consumo.getRegistro() - ds.getUltimoConsumo() ;
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(qntConsumido);
        bd.setScate(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);  
        double valorFormatado = bd.doubleValue();
        return qntConsumido;

    }

}
```

Ambas estão retornado o erro no trecho:

```
bd.setScate(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```

> ERRO The method setScate(int, int) is undefined for the type BigDecimal

Não estou conseguindo converter para 2 casas decimais, alguém sabe me dizer como deveria fazer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Método que não existe

A mensagem de erro "*method ??? is undefined*" significa que o método não existe.

Isso poderia ocorrer se estivesse usando diferentes versões do Java ou de alguma biblioteca em tempo de compilação e em tempo de execução, por exemplo.

Entretanto, nesse caso, o método se chama [`setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) (de escala) e não `setScate` com `t` de tatu.

Configure corretamente uma IDE como Elipse, NetBeans ou IntelliJ e evite erros bobos.

### Objetos imutáveis

Também foi notado pelo próprio autor que ele não estava atualizando a variável `bd` com o valor arredondado.

Como descrito na documentação, `BigDecimal` é imutável. O mesmo ocorre com quase todos os tipos básicos do Java como `String` e `Integer` (e faz da classe `Calendar` uma ovelha negra).

Isso significa que cada método que transforma o valor de um `BigDecimal` na verdade retorna uma nova instância com o valor transformado, enquanto a instância original permanece com o mesmo valor.

Portanto, o correto é:

```
BigDecimal numero = new BigDecimal("3.14159");
BigDecimal numeroArredondado = numero.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```

Como resultado, teremos:

```
numero: 3.14159
numeroArredondado: 3.15
```

Comment: Realmente utluiz, me equivoquei qnto a sintaxe, nao conhecia até então o BigDecimal, esta sendo novo para mim. Corrigi conforme me orientou, mas mesmo assim ele não converte para as 2 casas decimais apenas, continua trazendo um numero bem extenso, em ambas as formas que postei na pergunta inicial, deixei a segunda forma como definitiva. Saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado para não converter paras as 2 casas decimais apenas? debuguei o código e não consegui encontrar o erro.
obrigado

Comment: utluiz, consegui, não estava passando a variavel novamente dessa forma bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);  corrigi e funcionou.
obrigado

Comment: @GeovaniRafaelSório Hum... boa pegada. Este é outro problema comum com BigDecimals.